# Interpolating missing time-series data

Tags: time-series, missing-data, nonlinear-regression, interpolation, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have time-series for creatinine levels in patients, which has missing samples, due to patients' irregular visits to doctors. The figure below represents the time-series for a patient.

[image: Time-series data for a patient's Creatinine levels]

**Task**: I need to interpolate the missing sample values, for which I can use other auxiliary data about the patient such as their age, gender, smoking habits, etc.

What would be a good direction to approach this task?

Comment: Please specify why you want to interpolate the data. This may strongly influence how you interpolate and whether interpolating is a good idea in the first place.

Comment: My eventual goal is to form clusters of patients that have similar creatinine progression patterns. But since the time-series have these missing data points, I can't use a similarity measure due to the unequal length series. If I do the interpolation I can use any similarity measure and clustering algorithm.

Comment: Sounds like you should rather be looking for a similarity measure that can deal with missing data points (which sounds like a good question for this site, unless already asked). Interpolating my introduce several biases to a similarity measure aimed at “regular” time series. To give a very simple example, depending on the interpolation method, time series with a relatively high amount missing data may be considered similar to each other due to being relatively smooth.

Comment: You're right that can be another way of doing it - Are you aware of any such similarity measures?

Comment: No, but as I said, this sounds like a good question for this site.